# first_name in django model

Tags: django, templates

how can I access to first_name of a user in django template?. for example my writer in django model is like this below :

`writer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Answer (score 1):

If `User` is the Django default user model, it's simply

```
writer.first_name
```

-- e.g. if your example is in a `post` model you're rendering,

```
{{ post.writer.first_name }}
```

in a template.

Comment: when I use your answer in my code, it's not work and display nothing(in template) !!

Comment: ``` <i> {{ news.writer.first_name }}</i> ` ``

Comment: Does the `writer` user have a first name assigned?

Comment: If you go to the admin and look at the user, does it have anything in the "first name" field?

Comment: when we edit a user in admin, we can add first name and last name for a user, it's true ??

Comment: Yes. My hunch is that the user doesn't have one set.

Answer (score 0):

I have somewhat of a similar setup and this works for me:

`models.py`

```
class Customers(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(("Customer name"), max_length=200)

class Licenses(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```
views.py
```

```
def licenses (request):
    lic = Licenses.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'licenses.html',{'lic': lic})
```

```
licenses.html
```

```
{% for license in lic %}
{{ license.customer.name }}
{% endfor %}
```